# Combinations of N letters from an alphabet of N different letters

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

I'm trying to determine the number of combinations of $N$ letters from an alphabet of $N$. For instance for $N = 2$, with alphabet $(A, B)$, I can obtain $AA$, $AB$ and $BB$, $BA$ and $AB$ are the same combination so they only count for one. For $N = 3$, with alphabet $(A, B, C)$, the result I obtain is $10$. I have a procedure starting from the number of partitions I can get for $N$, summing the combinations $C(N,e)$ where $e$ is the number of elements in the partition, and multiplying each combination by the factorial of the different arrangements in the partition. However, I can't find a more general formula, if  there is any.

---

EDIT:
To further illustrate, here is the case for N = 3. The three letters are taken out of the set $(A,B,C)$, which gives the following combinations: $AAA$, $BBB$, $CCC$, $AAB$, $AAC$, $BBA$, $BBC$, $CCA$, $CCB$, $ABC$.

Comment: Can you list the case $N=3$ explicitly?  I am not sure exactly the criteria is for 2 words to be the same combination

Comment: What combinations are treated as the same? Those with equal number of every letter?

Comment: To see this is a duplicate; choosing $k$ out of $n$ unique items is the same as choosing a combination of $k$ letters from an alphabet of $n$ letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you're looking for [combinations with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition):

$$\left(\binom{n}{k} \right) = \binom{n-1+k}{k} \ .$$

**Edit:** In general, this formula allows somebody to compute the number of ways that we can place $n$ objects in $k$ places, where repetition is allowed and, thus $k$ does not have to be less than $n$ as in the usual combinations.

In this specific question, we would have:

$$\left(\binom{N}{N} \right) = \binom{N-1+N}{N} = \frac{(2N-1)!}{N!(N-1)!} \ .$$

For $n=1,2,3,4,5\ldots$ we have as result $1,3,10,35,126\ldots$, which is OEIS sequence [A088218](https://oeis.org/A088218) (similar to OEIS sequence [A001700](https://oeis.org/A001700)).

Comment: You should at least explain what is $n$ and what is $k$.

Comment: @user: it seems that both n and k are the N asked in the question, thus the solution is the combinations of 2N-1 objects taken N at a time. It matches the results given in the question, which for N = 2 gave 3 = C(3,2), and for N = 3 gave 10 = C(5,3).

Comment: @user: I added more information, explaining the meaning of $n$ and $k$ and presenting some computation of values.

Comment: Interesting that https://oeis.org/draft/A001700 spells exactly the problem I was tackling: number of ways to put n indistinguishable balls into n distinguishable boxes. I had adapted the language to letters and alphabet, because I saw many problems specified that way here. And thanks for the link to OEIS. I should remember that when facing a problem, I could try to count the solution for the first few cases, and then look up the sequence in OEIS: all the properties and alternate formulas are listed in there.

Comment: It was thanks to @user that I went looking for extra info, in particular in OEIS.